Using "We" or "They" in 1 Thess 4:14
Is there any gramatical reason for using the word "We" instead of the word "They"?
Why would the beliefs of the living be compared to the resurrection of the dead, in the same verse?

Which versions use "they" instead of "we"?

None of them, what is the reason for inserting the word "we". Is it a necessary inference in greek or only the translators supposition?

The text in question reads:

"For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so them also
which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him." 1 Thessalonians 4:14
K.J.V.

The "we" speaks of the Apostle Paul and all the Christians in Thessalonica he is writing to. And, by implication, all Christians throughout the centuries who believe that Jesus died and rose again.
The "they" (which is "them in the K.J.V.) speak of those Christians who had already died, and who would yet die before Christ returned. The Christians who had already died had the same beliefs as the Christians being written to. The implication is that all the Christians who would yet die before Christ returned would share those same beliefs about Christ and his return.
There is no grammatical problem. The problem seems to be in identifying the two categories of Christians - living Christians, and dead Christians. But given that they all believed the same things, there is no problem. Nor is there any need to suppose that the phrase "if they believe" would be more accurate. The Greek text does not allow for that. The Greek text is not contested when it comes to Paul's use of the words "we" and "they".

I feel that the use of the phrase "if they believe" would be more accurate. However, I just found an answer that does not support what I thought, and I wanted to clarify what I was looking for.
The term "even so" or "in like manner" is used to make a comparison between the first part of the verse to the latter portion.
I just found what I was looking for  per copilot-GPT4 -
The difference in the translation of 1 Thessalonians 4:14, where some versions use “we believe” and others use “they believe,” can be attributed to the nuances in the original Greek text and the translators’ interpretation of the context.
In the original Greek, the phrase is “εἰ γὰρ πιστεύομεν” (ei gar pisteuomen), which translates directly to “for if we believe.” The use of “we” (πιστεύομεν) is a first-person plural verb, indicating that the speaker includes themselves and their audience in the statement. This is why many translations, such as the ESV, NIV, and NLT, use "we believe"12.
Translators aim to convey the most accurate meaning of the original text while making it understandable for contemporary readers. The choice of “we believe” emphasizes the shared faith of the author (Paul) and the readers (the Thessalonian Christians), reinforcing a sense of community and collective belief.

This Stack Exchange site requires a hermeneutical approach to answering questions about specific biblical verses. What people feel is not relevant.

[1Th 4:13-14 KJV]  But I would not have you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning them which are asleep, that ye sorrow not, even as others which have no hope. For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so them also which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him. - If we believe in Jesus resurrection, then (even so) we must believe in the resurrection of those who have died (hoping in) Jesus.

No one has even attempted to in a straightforward manner explain whether the word "we " is an assumption by the translators. The verse is perfectly understandable without it.  ... If believe that Jesus died and rose again (even so) them which sleep in Jesus will God bring with Him. a
